# Email to Case, Task has been created automatically

Tags: case, tasks, email2case

In my scenario, I don't want task to be created automatically when an email-to-case has been created. I checked the Routing address name and '**Create Task to Email**' is disabled but still the task is being created. What I am missing? How can I have the email-to-case functionality not to create any task on case creation?

Comment: Have you checked all other possibilities for the Task creation? Like, Processes, other workflows, Triggers and any sort of automation around the Case-Task objects?

Answer (score -1):

@Arnold Jr. brings up good suggestions. Salesforce has a [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000327515&type=1&mode=1) regarding this exact issue ("Create Task to Email" is disabled, but yet it still creates a task).

The two things that cause this behavior according to that article:

1. **Routing Address in Pending State**. Check your "Verification" column in your email-to-case settings.

   *Setup --> Email-to-case --> Routing Addresses*

   If the verification has not completed, please do so.
2. **Automated Case User's profile does not have access to Record Type**

   Find the record type being set in the email-to-case settings under
   the Routing Address

   Check your Automated Case User by going to *Setup --> Support
   Settings*. Confirm the profile on this user has access to the record
   type.